# Visual Studio 2008 keeps adding 3 folders to solution folder prefixed with "Visual Studio"

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, file, directory

For some reason, Visual Studio 2008 keeps adding three folders to my solution folder.  I always have to delete them so I don't accidentally add them to SVN.  How do I prevent these from being created?  This happens about once every couple weeks, but I haven't figured out when it happens.  We're probably going to convert all of our projects to Visual Studio 2010 later this year, but in the mean time, I'd like to figure this out.

If anyone knows how to write a Windows folder (or file) creation listener, I'll be able to track this down faster.  I'm imagining a Windows Service that displays a popup when a folder gets created somewhere in the Windows file system, and it's constantly listening.  I've had other situations where folders and files get created in Windows (in different project types in Visual Studio 2008 or Windows for that matter), so that might be a cool resource to have in the arsenal.

[image]

Comment: "I always have to delete them so I don't accidentally add them to SVN." Obviously it's better to keep them from being created in the first place, but you do know about `svn:ignore`, right?

Comment: yep.  I just posted something about SVN ignore.  ;-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028428/prevent-web-config-from-being-committed-in-svn .. although I like to get the root cause of everything.  I'm MacGyver you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That directory is probably set as your VS Projects location.  If you open Tools>Options and then click **Projects and Solutions**, it should show you the folder paths. VS will recreate these paths if you delete them.

After installing VS, they are usually set to something like:

> C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Interesting!!!  I think you figured out the mystery!  Check this out.  http://serverfault.com/questions/294263/how-to-detect-moment-when-mapped-network-drives-are-lost-on-windows-7  .. I've been sporadically losing my company's intranet mapped network drives because one our client's VPN connection times out on my machine.  That's precisely the location of these 3 paths you pointed out.  So what I'm observing is that when Visual Studio 2008 loses the VPN connection, it then loses the mapped drives, and therefore can't find these paths, and ends up putting them into the solution folder!

Comment: Here is an example path:  \\ourcompany.local\DFSRoot\Users\MacGyver\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2008\Projects

Comment: It probably just defaults to the solution directory if the path doesn't exist.

Comment: meant to say when "Windows loses the VPN connection